# Java jackson - update array in json

Tags: java, json, jackson-databind

I am new to java jackson. I want to parse through a json String and replace one of the array's present in it (whose size is 1) with the array of size 2 by copying the same contents of the array value. Eg: Input json file

```
{
  "order_info": {
    "order_number": "123456",
    "order_date": "2019-11-08T10:23:29.502Z",
    "attributes": {
      "checkout_locale": "en_US"
    },
    "order_items": [
      {
        "categories": [
          "Clothing"
        ],
        "is_backordered": false,
        "vendors": [
          {
            "name": "zxcx"
          }
        ],
        "discount_amount": 0,
        "final_sale_date": "2019-03-01T20:07:16Z"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Output json required:

```
{
  "order_info": {
    "order_number": "123456",
    "order_date": "2019-11-08T10:23:29.502Z",
    "attributes": {
      "checkout_locale": "en_US"
    },
    "order_items": [
      {
        "categories": [
          "Clothing"
        ],
        "is_backordered": false,
        "vendors": [
          {
            "name": "zxcx"
          }
        ],
        "discount_amount": 0,
        "final_sale_date": "2019-03-01T20:07:16Z"
      },
      {
        "categories": [
          "Clothing"
        ],
        "is_backordered": false,
        "vendors": [
          {
            "name": "zxcx"
          }
        ],
        "discount_amount": 0,
        "final_sale_date": "2019-03-01T20:07:16Z"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried code as below :

```
   ObjectNode objectNode = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(ordersApiBasePayload);
   ArrayNode nodeArray = (ArrayNode) jsonNode.get("order_info").get("order_items");
   ArrayNode items = objectNode.putArray("order_items");
   items.add(nodeArray.get(0));
   items.add(nodeArray.get(0));
```

But, by doing it this way, i do not get the existing order_items replaced with new two order_items. I get the new two order_items appended at the end of the json like below:

```
{
  "order_info": {
    "order_number": "123456",
    "order_date": "2019-11-08T10:23:29.502Z",
    "attributes": {
      "checkout_locale": "en_US"
    },
    "order_items": [
      {
        "categories": [
          "Clothing"
        ],
        "is_backordered": false,
        "vendors": [
          {
            "name": "zxcx"
          }
        ],
        "discount_amount": 0,
        "final_sale_date": "2019-03-01T20:07:16Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  "order_items": [
    {
      "categories": [
        "Clothing"
      ],
      "is_backordered": false,
      "vendors": [
        {
          "name": "zxcx"
        }
      ],
      "discount_amount": 0,
      "final_sale_date": "2019-03-01T20:07:16Z"
    },
    {
      "categories": [
        "Clothing"
      ],
      "is_backordered": false,
      "vendors": [
        {
          "name": "zxcx"
        }
      ],
      "discount_amount": 0,
      "final_sale_date": "2019-03-01T20:07:16Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: nodeArray.add(nodeArray.get(0)) does not work?

Comment: nodeArray.add(nodeArray.get(0)) updates the nodeArray Object with two values of order_items. But, how to replace the existing order_items in the objectNode with this new nodeArray?

Comment: nodeArray after nodeArray.add(nodeArray.get(0)) -->
[
  {
    "categories": [
      "Clothing"
    ],
    "is_backordered": false,
    "vendors": [
      {
        "name": "zxcx"
      }
    ],
    "discount_amount": 0,
    "final_sale_date": "2019-03-01T20:07:16Z"
  },
  {
    "categories": [
      "Clothing"
    ],
    "is_backordered": false,
    "vendors": [
      {
        "name": "zxcx"
      }
    ],
    "discount_amount": 0,
    "final_sale_date": "2019-03-01T20:07:16Z"
  }
]

Comment: If you would like to update item with index 0, you can use nodeArray.set(0, <your new node>); Or you can replace whole array with ((ObjectNode) jsonNode.get("order_info")).putArray("order_items"); and than add your items.

Comment: Yeah @JanCizmar it worked. Thanks!